# Image transforms directory not being created

Tags: assets, image-transforms, image, responsive-images

I've upgraded to El Capitan from Yosemite, created several Image Transforms in the CP (see pic) but they don't seem to be creating the folders in the uploads dir. I've checked folder permissions for the assets dir and all have read and write and double checked the folder paths.

I'm running on Craft Pro ver: 2.6.2796

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Orci.jpg)

The code I'm using in the template is as follows:

```
{% set xxxlarge = transform(bgImage, 'bigImageXx') %}
{% set small = transform(bgImage, 'bigImageS') %}
{% set medium = transform(bgImage, 'bigImageM') %}
{% set large = transform(bgImage, 'bigImageL') %}
{% set xlarge = transform(bgImage, 'bigImageX') %}
{% set xxlarge = transform(bgImage, 'bigImage') %}


<picture class="ce-mast-background">
    <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
    <source srcset="{{ xxxlarge }}, {{ xxxlarge }} 2x" media="(min-width: 1281px)">
    <source srcset="{{ xxlarge }}, {{ xxlarge }} 2x" media="(min-width: 800px)">
    <source srcset="{{ medium }}, {{ large }} 2x" media="(min-width: 400px)">
    <source srcset="{{ small }}, {{ medium }} 2x">
    <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
    <img srcset="{{ xxxlarge }}" alt="{{ entry.title }}" class="ce-mast-image" />

</picture>
```

Comment: When you say they're not being created, what's happening?  Are you getting an error message? If you view source, is a URL being generated for the image?

Comment: Are you using any third party plugins to enable the scrset attribute?